# Was not been offered

Tags: usage

Is the use of **was not been offered** grammatically correct in the following sentence?

While Friday prayers were not allowed in the historic Jamia Masjid in Nowhatta area for 13th week, Khoj-e-Digar — the special evening prayer held at Naqashband Sahib shrine here — was not allowed on Friday.
It was for the first time that Khoj-e-Digar, which is a centuries-old tradition specific to Kashmiri Muslims, **was not been offered**.

I think it is not but I found it in a newspaper.

Comment: It is not correct. I suspect that this a copywriting mistake--the writer waffled between *was offered* and *had not been offered* and neglected to correct completely from one to the other.

Comment: "Was not been" is *never* used. "Was not offered" would be correct here. By the way, perhaps the last sentence should begin, "It was the first time.....". (Sad news, Piyush.)

Comment: It was probably meant to be **was not being offered**.